# grouping by weekly days pandas

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe,df containing

```
 Index         Date & Time        eventName       eventCount
 0            2017-08-09              ABC            24
 1            2017-08-09              CDE           140
 2            2017-08-10              CDE           150
 3            2017-08-11              DEF           200
 4            2017-08-11              ABC            20
 5            2017-08-16              CDE            10
 6            2017-08-16              ABC            15
 7            2017-08-17              CDE            10
 8            2017-08-17              DEF            50
 9            2017-08-18              DEF            80
     ...
```

I want to sum the eventCount for each weekly day occurrences and plot for the total events for each weekly day(from MON to SUN) i.e. for example:
 Summation of the eventCount values of:

```
2017-08-09 and 2017-08-16(Mondays)=189 
2017-08-10 and 2017-08-17(Tuesdays)=210
2017-08-16 and 2017-08-23(Wednesdays)=300
```

I have tried

```
dailyOccurenceSum=df['eventCount'].groupby(lambda x: x.weekday).sum()
```

and I get this error:AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `df.groupby(df['Date & Time'].dt.weekday_name).eventCount.sum()`

Comment: @COLDSPEED it didn't work,I got this error:  AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: So convert Date&Time to a datetime column.. pd.to_datetime(df[...], errors='coerce') and then run the same code.

Comment: It didn't work!!!!!

Comment: Okay. Let me say this as simply as possible. Programmers are not geniuses. We are not mindreaders. If you said "it doesn't work", do you expect me to magically understand why? You have to tell me what went wrong, whether the answer is incorrect, or you received an error. Alright? Please tell me _why_ it went wrong, and a little more context such as your code, and expected output helps a lot.

Comment: my bad,here is the error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: So, your column name has the same name as an inbuilt function, so use `df.groupby(df['Date & Time'].dt.weekday_name)["eventCount"].sum()` With the `["xxx"]` instead of `.xxx`

Comment: You are a genius!!! maybe not all programmers....it worked a great deal!

Comment: Is it possible to sort the index? like starting with Monday,tuesday,wednesday,..... instead of Friday,monday,saturday...

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Give me 2 minutes to write an answer explaining how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with `df` -

```
df

   Index Date & Time eventName  eventCount
0      0  2017-08-09       ABC          24
1      1  2017-08-09       CDE         140
2      2  2017-08-10       CDE         150
3      3  2017-08-11       DEF         200
4      4  2017-08-11       ABC          20
5      5  2017-08-16       CDE          10
6      6  2017-08-16       ABC          15
7      7  2017-08-17       CDE          10
8      8  2017-08-17       DEF          50
9      9  2017-08-18       DEF          80
```

First, convert `Date & Time` to a `datetime` column -

```
df['Date & Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date & Time'])
```

Next, call `groupby` + `sum` on the weekday name.

```
df = df.groupby(df['Date & Time'].dt.weekday_name)['eventCount'].sum()
df

Date & Time
Friday       300
Thursday     210
Wednesday    189
Name: eventCount, dtype: int64
```

If you want to sort by weekday, convert the index to categorical and call `sort_index` -

```
cat = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday']

df.index = pd.Categorical(df.index, categories=cat, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_index()
df

Wednesday    189
Thursday     210
Friday       300
Name: eventCount, dtype: int64
```

Comment: for the sort index code,i got this: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Categorical'

Comment: @Bode You need to update your pandas version. The latest is 0.21.

Comment: could you help out with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933691/grouping-by-day-of-the-week-pandas

Comment: @Bode I've answered you there. Take a look.