# grouping by day of the week pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
  I have a dataframe,df 

        Index       eventName Count   pct
     2017-08-09       ABC     24     95.00%
     2017-08-09       CDE    140     98.50%
     2017-08-10       DEF    200     50.00%
     2017-08-11       CDE    150     99.30%
     2017-08-11       CDE    150     99.30%
     2017-08-16       DEF    200     50.00%
     2017-08-17       DEF    200     50.00%
```

I want to group by daily weekly occurrence by counting the values in the column pct. for example, we now have:

```
 2017-08-09 has 2 values in pct column  and  2017-08-16 has 1 value in pct, then we have Monday:3 
  2017-08-10  has 1 value and 2017-08-17 has 1 value,then we have Tuesday:2 and so on
```

then the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
    Index        Count   
 Monday            3
 Tuesday           2
 Wednesday         2
```

I have tried `df2=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).size().sort_values(ascending=False)` 
but its not grouping by day of the week and not transforming to the date index to words

Comment: when i tried your line:
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'weekday_name'

Comment: Is `Index` the actual index? Or is it a column called Index?

Comment: It is an actual index

Comment: My answer would work then, try it and let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wen's answer with `value_counts` is good, but does not account for the possibility of `NaN`s in the `pct` column.

---

Assuming `Index` is the index, you can call `groupby` + `count` -

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby(df.index.weekday_name).pct.count()

Index
Friday       2
Thursday     2
Wednesday    3
Name: pct, dtype: int64
```

To sort on weekday, convert to `pd.Categorical`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47937620/4909087).

Comment: I got an error: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: @Bode Typo, check again

Comment: @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ    Create a list of colors 
      colors = ["#E13F29", "#D69A80", "#D63B59", "#AE5552", "#CB5C3B", "#EB8076", "#96624E"]
     df.plot().pie(df ['pct'],df.index,shadow=False,colors=color    s, explode=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', )
    # View the plot drop above
    pyplot.axis('equal')
    # View the plot
    pyplot.tight_layout()
    pyplot.show()                           But I keep getting KeyError: 'pct'

Comment: @Bode Can you open a new question? I don't think it's related.

Answer (score 2):

By using `value_counts`

```
df.Index=pd.to_datetime(df.Index)
df.Index.dt.weekday_name.value_counts()
Out[994]: 
Wednesday    3
Thursday     2
Friday       2
Name: Index, dtype: int64
```

Comment: i got this using the code:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: @Bode ummm. `df=df.reset_index()` then `df['Index']=pd.to_datetime(df['Index'])`

Comment: @Bode check your column name , whether it is index or Index ?

Comment: just checked, it is Index

Comment: @djk47463 yeah.....I asked the same question before .....seems like he have the upper case ...

Comment: C:\Users\Bode\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:551: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
C:\Users\Bode\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:2746: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.rename(columns={'Index': 'New_name'}, inplace=True)

df['New_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['New_name'])

df['Day_df'] = df['New_name'].dt.weekday_name

df.groupby(['Day_df']).count()
```

Comment: i got this:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Index'

Comment: try renaming the name column? xD

Comment: KeyError: 'New_name'